# How to enable http extension in php using php.ini?

Tags: php, hosting

How to enable http extension for PHP with shared godaddy hosting in the quickest way; preferably uploading a `php.ini` file to website directory root - but how do I write it? *I'm currently having issues with out of the box shared godaddy hosting as I am trying to parse data using PHP from a 3rd party API*

Comment: what http extension? url support for fopen(), you mean?\

Comment: GoDaddy has a [support page](http://support.godaddy.com/). Use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [`PECL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php) extension, to install it you need the permission from Godaddy to do so. It's better to raise a support ticket and ask them to do it for you.

Comment: Damn mate. This is what I hate with Godaddy.

Comment: Yeah, I think they used to be good like 5 years ago but lately their getting pretty bad. Cheers.